# Fastest way to get the blob file name from Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to list the blob files name from Azure storage. I don't want the contents present in the blob files, just want to list the name.

Here is my current approach.

```
public static async Task<List<string>> GetBlobList()
{
    var cloudBlobContainer = await CreateCloudBlobContainer();
    BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

    List<string> blobList = new List<string>();

    do
    {
        BlobResultSegment response;

        response = await cloudBlobContainer
                            .ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, true, BlobListingDetails.None, 5000, continuationToken, null, null);

        continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;

        foreach (CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob in response.Results.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>())
        {
            blobList.Add(cloudBlob.Name);
        }
    }
    while (continuationToken != null);
    return blobList;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but to retrieve 11000 blob file names its takes around **10 seconds** on an average.

Is there a way to improve it ? I'm not looking for concrete answers here, pointers should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea that may accelerate to list the blob names within multi-threading.

According to the API reference [`CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobssegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet) as below, the first parameter `prefix` of this method can be used to list these blob names started with the `prefix` value, such as `abc.txt` started with prefix `a`.

[image]

So assumption that these blob names in a container are started with `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or other valid characters, or these prefix words you known in the container, you can concurrently list these blob names of different prefix word within multi-threading to reduce the time cost for getting chained the next list via `ContinuationToken`.

Meanwhile, if you get the responses of multi-threadings by the ordered prefix words, the final merged list is ordered without additional sort operation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is already the fastest implementation to retrieve all blob file names.

However, maybe you can slightly improve the performance by hosting a tiny REST API on e. g. Azure Function that is located in the same location as your Blob Storage. This function then *only* returns a list of names (ListBlobsSegmentedAsync does return more metadata which increases the payload / loading time). You will also have only one remote request using this approach.

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question. In new Azure Function you function you are suggesting, shouldn't we have to use the same code to get the blob file names ?

Comment: yes, you would use the same code.  But instead of sending the blob file name + other properties from azure to the client, you will only send the blob file name to the client.